# Laravel запрос к БД с выбором нужных полей

Tags: база-данных, laravel, orm, eloquent

У меня есть 2 модели Flat n и Layout

```
class Flat extends Model
public function plan(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Layout', 'plan_id');
}
```

Я делаю запрос в контроллере такого типа

```
$data = Flat::whereIn('floor', $floors )->with('plan')->whereHas(
                'plan' , function($query) use($rooms, $squareFrom, $squareTo) {
                $query->whereIn('rooms', $rooms);
                $query->whereBetween('total_square',[$squareFrom, $squareTo]);
            })->get();
```

Фильтры работают как надо. Данные приходят правильные. Но мне нужны только некоторые поля.

Вопрос: Как правильно сделать выбор нужных мне полей?

П.С. Когда я делаю запрос такого вида:

```
$data = Flat::select('id', 'section')->whereIn('floor', $floors )->with('plan')->whereHas(
                'plan' , function($query) use($rooms, $squareFrom, $squareTo) {
                $query->whereIn('rooms', $rooms);
                $query->whereBetween('total_square',[$squareFrom, $squareTo]);
            })->get();
```

или

```
$data = Flat::whereIn('floor', $floors )->with('plan')->whereHas(
                'plan' , function($query) use($rooms, $squareFrom, $squareTo) {
                $query->whereIn('rooms', $rooms);
                $query->whereBetween('total_square',[$squareFrom, $squareTo]);
            })->get(['id', 'section']);
```

то у меня появляется ошибка

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)Trying to get property 'square' of non-object
```

она вылезает на методе модели Flat, где идет обращение к связанной модели Layout

```
    public function getPriceAttribute(){
        return $this->coast_for_meter * $this->plan->square;
    }
```

В других контроллерах этот метод работает нормально, я уверенна что ошибка не в методе.
Как все таки правильно составить запрос, чтобы выводились только нужные параметры?

Answer (score 0):

Сама отвечу на свой вопрос. Оказывается селект срабатывал, но не срабатывали методы модели, потому что надо было указать поле по которому модели связываются, все логично, то есть надо было в селекте указать plan_id

```
  $data = Flat::select(['id','plan_id', 'floor', 'section', 'number'])->whereIn('floor', $floors )->with('plan')->whereHas(
                'plan' , function($query) use($rooms, $squareFrom, $squareTo) {
                $query->whereIn('rooms', $rooms)->whereBetween('total_square', [$squareFrom, $squareTo]);
            })->get();
```